# how to make fields required in django restframework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, backend

I build a blog API and the Post model is:
the problem is when i want to create a post with no body content the error is

```
class Post(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('P', _('Published')),
        ('D', _('Draft')),
        ('R', _('reject'))
    ]
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("title"), max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    lead = models.CharField(verbose_name=_(
        "lead"), max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("context"))
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_(
        "thumbnail"), upload_to='posts', blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, verbose_name=_(
        "author"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(
        _("status"), max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_CHOICES[1][0])
    publish_time = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=_("published at"), default=timezone.now)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=_("created at"), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=_("updated at"), auto_now=True)

    category = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category, verbose_name=_("Categorys"), related_name='Categorys')
    like_count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("like"), default=0)
    dislike_count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_("dislike"), default=0)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish_time']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
class PostListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    dietale_url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='api:Post_detail'
    )
    author = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'author',
            'lead',
            'dietale_url',
        ]

    def get_author(self, obj):
        return obj.author.name
```

the problem is when i want to create a post it return the erorr:

```
{
    "title": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

**There are more fields required like author body and ...**

**whay just the title is the required field what happens to other fields**

Comment: rest of the fields have null=True, meaning these fields can be nullable, hence not required

Answer (score 0):

Your `title` cannot be `blank` or `null` in your django model and the serializer you use is the `ModelSerializer`, so it will be automatically required.

You need to remove `blank = True` and `null = True` if you don't want your fields to be required (or override you fields in serializer)

[Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required):

> If you're using Model Serializer default value will be False if you
> have specified blank=True or default or null=True at your field in
> your Model.